# Drupal - allowing editing of content by others

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm building a site that will have users who can create teams, and I want to allow any member of the team to edit any of the team's content--but only the content of teams they are on. I've found modules like Content Access and Node Access that allow you to create roles and assign access from there, but you still have to manually assign users to those roles.

It looks like this means that I would need to create a roll for each team and assign each team member to that role? That seems too complicated.

Since users can assign themselves to teams, is there a module that will read which users are associated with a particular team and allow them to edit content/nodes for only that team?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [**Organic Groups** modules](https://drupal.org/project/og) enables "users to create and manage their own 'groups'".

Your implementation could be similar to drupal.org’s own use of this module on https://groups.drupal.org/. Every user can join groups and create content for this group (and some content types can be edited by anyone else from this group).